# How to paste outside unity copied text in to input fields in unity in webgl build

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have tried to paste outside unity copied text in to inputfield in webgl build but text is not copied in input field. Is there any way to achieve this. Please suggest any idea. Thanks in advance.

For example open Notepad (windows) or TextEdit (mac), select some text, copy, click in a InputField in a Unity WebGL app running in the browser. Paste (ctrl-v/cmd-v) and nothing happens.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You want to copy text from where to where?

Comment: Thanks for responce, I have copied text from document and try to paste copied text in input fields in unity web gl build but text is not copied.

Comment: Where is the copy and paste code?

Comment: I just copied text from document  using ctrl + c key and trying to past the copied text in input field i have used like ctrl + v key.

Answer (score 3):

I threw together [this solution](https://github.com/greggman/unity-webgl-copy-and-paste) which seems to work.

Basically it hooks into the browser's cut, copy, and paste events. On paste it gets the browser's clipboard and passes it into Unity to append to the current `InputField`. On cut/copy it calls into Unity to tell the current `InputField` to do a cut/copy and then it gets unity's clipboard and puts it into the browser's clipboard.

I tested it on Firefox 77 Windows, Chrome 83 Windows, and Chrome 83 Mac, Firefox 77 Mac, Safari 13.1 Mac.

Also as I was posting this I found this solution which is arguably better?

https://github.com/kou-yeung/WebGLInput

Comment: Hi, I tried your first solution. Copy, Cut and Paste working only within the browser. While I need to copy text from Notepad++ or Excel and Paste in WebGL app, and for now it is not working.

Comment: Oh, I should delete panel to make it work. In the scene I deleted the panel and instead added gameobject. Now it works! Thank you very much!

Comment: the second solution works great for me.  https://github.com/kou-yeung/WebGLInput

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, you **can't** copy and paste when using WebGL with Unity.

This is due to browser security restriction. Although, Unity has been [working](https://forum.unity.com/threads/copy-paste-has-anyone-built-a-good-solution-for-this.401851/) on a copy and paste mechanism for WebGL by using keyboard shortcuts to perform the copy and paste which is now supported on some web browsers but this has not been released yet. It's not done yet so you'll have to wait until then.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please suggest any alternative for implement this type of feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two steps:

1. Create javascript library with function that calls javasript "prompt" window in which user can paste from clipboard.
2. Use "SendMessage" to send user's input from javascript to your Unity method.

You can find full description of this solution in this thread: https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-copy-paste-for-input-field-not-working.494765/

Answer (score 0):

```
I was facing the same issue while developing paste functionality into my Unity project.
The requirement was user can paste the copied data into the InputFiled.
```

Official document link: https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

```
I follow these steps: -
 1. Create a javascript plugin for the same with the .jslib file extension.
 2. Paste this code into the created file.

    mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, {
        CopyPasteReader: function(gObj, vName) {
                var gameObjectName = UTF8ToString(gObj);
                var voidName = UTF8ToString(vName);
                console.log(gameObjectName, "gameObjectName");
                console.log(voidName, "voidName");
                navigator.clipboard.readText().then(function(data) {
                    SendMessage(gameObjectName,"Paste", data);
                }, function() {
                    SendMessage(gameObjectName, "Paste", "no text available in clipboard");
                })
            }
            });

 3. Import this plugin into the script top.

    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    public static extern void CopyPasteReader(string gObj, string vName);

 2. Use the Update function so it will call automatically after the frame change.

    void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V) && (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightControl)))
            {
                CopyPasteReader("KYCDigilockerurlPanel","Paste");
            }
        }
    // here KYCDigilockerurlPanel is a top parent of inputfield and Pase is a function


 4. This function will check if the ctrl+v action has performed the run the "CopyPasteReader("KYCDigilockerurlPanel", "Paste");" function. 

 5. Crate a Paste function in your script file

    private void Paste(string pasteValue)
    {
        Debug.Log(pasteValue + " pasteValue");
        enterDigiLockerCode.text = pasteValue;
    }
    // here enterDigiLockerCode is an input field name

6. Attach the script on the panel "KYCDigilockerurlPanel"  and create a GameObject of that Input field where you want to paste.
```